# Upgrade okhttp to 3.14.x in react native project

Tags: react-native, okhttp

We ran into a bug in our react-native project that is related to the okhttp library on android.

RN uses okhttp 3.12.1, while the [bug we encountered](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4570) was fixed in 3.14.4.
I added the dependencies to my andorid/app/build.gradle file.

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.14.9")
```

Everything seems to work fine.

Is this the correct way to do it. Are there any obvious issues I might run into with this?

*I'm sorry that this is not a typical q/a question. But I'm not sure where the correct place for this question is.*

Comment: thank you, I used this method to override to use okhttp version 4 to fix app crashing on Android 11 with targetSdk 30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that OkHttp versions greater than 3.12.x [require Android 5+](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5/).

One issue is that OkHttp 3.14.x is no longer supported. Only 3.12.x and 4.x [get security fixes](https://square.github.io/okhttp/security/). And 4.x is the only line getting big fixes.

[Upgrading to OkHttp 4.x](https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/) is safe and easy.

Comment: oh. thank you. That's why react native didn't upgrade to 3.14